# Spotify API track request with more artist details

Tags: api, spotify

Is it possible to make a request to get a spotify track and also request that the artist object contains their avatar?
Sample request `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/60EtWSoDRJSFmg99MKZi0x`
Is it possible to get the artist's avatar url in the artist object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to make another request. Embedded artist objects (in tracks and albums) all seem to be of the simplified type, which do not include images of the artist. See: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/

1. Fetch https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/60EtWSoDRJSFmg99MKZi0x
2. Parse response
3. Fetch https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/49gaZqfow2v8EEQmjGyEIw

Comment: Ok, thats what I'm doing as of now. Is there any plan to add something like this in?If not is it possible to get the first artist given a track's id? With that I could run the requests in parallel instead of series.

Comment: Don't know, but this is definitely the wrong forum to ask. Request features for the Spotify Web API at https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues I think it sounds like a totally reasonable thing to want to have.